# Usage of Dapr Virtual Actors vs Orleans

Tags: microservices, actor, orleans, dapr

I was looking at virtual Actors and I pumped into Dapr and Orleans.

I understand that Dapr is a more complete framework to build a microservices architecture, where virtual actors are just one part of the many provided components.

But focusing uniquely on the virtual actors aspect, I wanted to understand what are the main differences/relationship between both products (except the fact that dapr is language agnostic) and when one should use one vs the other.

Are there any use cases where we would prefer using Orleans instead of Dapr Actors while still relying on Dapr as main microservice architecture framework?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image: benchmark for requests per second for major actor frameworks]

For me, it was about flexibility and performance. Orleans is slightly more opinionated than Akka.NET (easier to learn, imho), more fully-featured than Proto.Actor, and enormously faster than DAPR on pure throughput.

( graphic from https://www.etteplan.com/stories/comparing-net-virtual-actor-frameworks )